# sonarqube v4.3 cobertura reports

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, cobertura, jacoco

I was using sonar 4.2 and sonar-runner 2.3 and cobertura plugin.

After upgrade sonar to 4.3 and sonar-runner to 2.4, all my projects are with 0% coverage.

On log contains:

```
14:57:28.135 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
14:57:28.135 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: C:\Desenvolvimento\shared_view\SILCE\TE151\03-Implementacao\Componentes\caixa-util\target\jacoco.exec
14:57:28.464 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 329 ms
14:57:29.089 INFO  - Execute decorators...
```

My sonar-project.properties:

```
#http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters


# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=br.gov.caixa:caixa-util
sonar.projectName=caixa-util
sonar.projectVersion=1.000


# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src

# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=test

# path to project binaries (optional), for example directory of Java bytecode
sonar.binaries=build/classes

# optional comma-separated list of paths to libraries. Only path to JAR file and path to directory of classes are supported.
sonar.libraries=../caixa-lib/lib/cobertura/1.9.4.1/cobertura.jar,../caixa-lib/lib/cache/ehcache-core-2.5.0.jar



# Uncomment this line to analyse a project which is not a java project. 
# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
#sonar.language=cobol

# Additional parameters
#my.property=value

#clearcase
sonar.scm.url=scm\:clearcase|caixa-util


#coverage
#teste de cobertura
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/docs-temp/junit
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=build/docs/cobertura-reports/coverage.xml
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the version of cobertura, jacoco and java plugin ?  Thx.

Comment: Sonar and plugins are up to date.
cobertura plugin version: 1.6
To analyze my code, cobertura 1.9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

We have an issue on Java 2.2 and Cobertura 1.6 : The reuse report on Cobertura 1.6 is not working and so you will have to wait for fix version java 2.2.1 and cobertura 1.6.1 to be released (This will happen shortly, vote is open on SonarQube dev mailing list : http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-VOTE-Cobertura-version-1-6-1-td5024837.html
and http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-VOTE-Java-Plugin-version-2-2-1-td5024834.html
).

Please note that with these version, as the tests won't be executed by SonarQube analysis anymore, you will have to generate the cobertura reports yourself : check http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cobertura+Plugin